# How to reword "put forward a new criticism"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Suppose, somebody made a critical remark. And then another one. According to google I cannot say:

> "He issued a new criticism",
>
> "He made a new criticism", or
>
> "He put forward a new criticism".

What is the standard expression?

Comment: I'm not sure what the context is, but a common phrase is "brought up". So, "he brought up a new idea" or "she brought up a good point". I think it could be used for your situation as "he brought up a new criticism of"

Comment: Google says "No results found for "he brought up a new criticism of"."

Comment: what about "He made **another** criticism "

Comment: Only 7 results  :(

Comment: I think, there must be other ways to imply this meaning. It seems that, this is not a natural sentence. Perhaps, you should use the verb "criticize"

Comment: For example: this time, he criticized her for laziness! or "he continued  and criticized her appearance", He didn't stop and start criticizing about her beauty" I am not sure, I am learner. Lets wait for the natives

Comment: No, I need a noun here (later I refer to that comment)

Comment: @Serguei - In all fairness, Google does not contain every single possible sentence ever.  It's always possible to create new, *perfectly valid* sentences or phrases in English that have never existed before, so not finding them with Google doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I understand that. But when  for such a short and presumably common expression as "He has another criticism" Google finds no results at all, this makes one suspect that something is wrong, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

We can [**raise** or **bring**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raised%20a%20criticism%2Cbrought%20a%20criticism&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Craised%20a%20criticism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbrought%20a%20criticism%3B%2Cc0) a criticism. We can also **level** a criticism.

Comment: May it be something wrong with the word "new" then? Because google finds only 4 (!) results for "brought a new criticism" and 3 results for "raised a new criticism"

Comment: Google's text-base has its limitations.  But that wouldn't be a new criticism.

Comment: So, it's google's glitch and for a native speaker the sentence "He brought a new criticism" is perfectly normal?

Comment: Yes, that would be a normal phrase, though less frequent than "raised"; and it's not a Google 'glitch'; many thousands of books and articles are published every year but their contents do not become part of Google's text-base. A standard Google-search goes against the public content of websites and nothing more.